# How can I find the IP of my router?

Tags: macos, router, network

We have Bell (Canada) as an ISP. Their service works fine, I can also easily see what devices are connected to the home network via their [home network settings](https://internet.bell.ca/index.cfm?method=content.view&category_id=674&content_id=12802).

Additionally, I have my own modem, a [Zhone 6518-A1-NA](http://www.zhone.com/products/6518-A1/). I want to use it as a bridge, so it connects to the home network, and afterwards I can connect my network drive to it.

The issue is that I cannot find the IP of that Zhone modem, which is connected via ethernet cable to my computer directly (not the ISP's modem). I reset it, but I can't find the information as of what its IP would be and I can't connect to it to change its firmware or whatever I wish to do.

Is there a way from the Terminal or the network settings to find out what its IP is? Keep in mind I tried calling the ISP and they said that because I am on a Mac and also because it's not their own product, they will offer no support.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which IP are you looking for? The one on your local network (Mac -> Router) or the one on the Internet (Internet -> Router)?

Comment: I realize now I wasn't clear enough indeed. I mean to find the IP of the local network (Mac -> router/modem [connected via ethernet cable])

Comment: Maybe you can try to edit your question to clarify what you are looking for and how your setup is ([ask] may help here as well).

Comment: Try turning your wifi off and see if that helps with any of the suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

`System Preferences -> Network -> Pick your Adapter -> Advanced -> TCP/IP Tab` :)

See screenshot here: [image]

Your computer's IP is marked "**IPv4 Address**" (`192.168.1.74`) and your router's IP is marked "**Router**" (i.e. `192.168.1.1` in my case).

Comment: But doesn't that give me the IP of my own computer? If I use that IP in my browser, I cannot reach my modem's config page with that IP.

Comment: Unfortunately, the router line is empty...

Comment: @jansensan In the configure IPv4 drop down, are you 'Using DHCP'? If you don't know what your IP addresses should be, you should be using DHCP

Answer (score 0):

MAC user :)

1. Click on the apple (top left)
2. About this MAC
3. More Info
4. System Report
5. WiFi

Will tell you the IP of the device you are connected to and more.

Comment: Hmm no, that would provide me with the IP of the ISP's modem, which is of no use to me currently. I want the Zhone one, which is connected to my computer via Ethernet. (Sorry if I wasn't clear enough)

Comment: So you use Zone modem/router on your computer to connect, OK, same as above but click on the Modems. What does the Ethernet card say ? You Mac must know the hardware info in the System information.

Comment: Alternatively, Reset your modem/router to factory settings (small toothpick hole in the back), that you will get the log in page IP address and so on. Warning, you must know the log in info ! (but do not panic (normally it is set to "admin + admin"...(or printed on the back label.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the routers default ip should be 192.168.1.1. From the [manual](http://www.zhone.com/support/manuals/docs/830/830-03750-01.pdf):

> Configuring Your Computer Prior to accessing the router through the
>   LAN or the USB port, note the following necessary configurations
>
> - Your PC’s TCP/IP address: 192.168.1.__( the last number is any number
>     between 2 and 254)
> - The router’s default IP address: 192.168.1.1
> - Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
>
> Below are the procedures for configuring
>   your computer. Follow the instructions for the operating system that
>   you are using. If you used the Ethernet cable to connect your router
>   and PC, you do not need any specific driver installation.

Comment: I have tried this IP, however I cannot reach it. There may be an interference with the ISP's modem.

Comment: Then unplug the modem and try it.